# DB2 Exclusive Lock Not Released

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-luw

In a particularly requested DB2 table, accessed by distributed Java desktop applications via JDBC, I'm getting the following scenario several times a day:

1. Client A wants to INSERT new registers and gets a IX lock on the table, and X locks in each new row;
2. Other client(s) want(s) to perform a SELECT, is granted a IS lock on the table, but the application stucks;
3. Client A continues to work, but the INSERT and UPDATE queries are not commited, the locks are not released, and it keeps collecting X locks to each row;
4. Client A exits and **its work is not committed**. The other clients finnally get their SELECT result set.

Used to work well, and it does most of the time, but the lock situations are getting more and more frequent.

Auto-commit is ON.

There are no exceptions thrown or errors detected in the logs.

DB2 9.5 / JDBC Driver 9.1 (JDBC 3 specification)

Answer (score 0):

If the jdbc applications are not performing COMMIT then the locks will persist until a rollback or commit. If an application quits with uncommitted inserts then a rollback will happen for all recent versions of Db2. This is expected behaviour for Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows.

If the jdbc application is failing to commit then it is broken or misconfigured so you must get to root cause of that if you seek a permanent solution.

If the other clients wish to ignore the insert row-locks then they should choose the correct isolation level *and* you can configure Db2 to skip insert-locks . See documentation DB2_SKIPINSERTED at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.regvars.doc/doc/r0005665.html#r0005665__P_DB2_SKIPINSERTED)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that sometimes the auto-commit, and I don't know why, becomes off to a random single instance of the application.

The following validation seems to solve the problem (but not the root of it):

```
if (!conn.getAutoCommit()) {

    conn.commit();
}
```